# Is there a way in R to add a row underneath that calculates difference of above rows (tidyr/dplyr)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a really simple question but am not able to figure out at all.

| animal | age |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 12 |
| dog | 8 |

Normally I'd apply `data %>% mutate(diff = age[1] - age[2])`, but it adds a column beside, whereas I'd like a row underneath.

Below is the output I'd like. The difference row simply calculates the age of the cat minus age of the dog. So here are two example outputs:

| animal | age |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 12 |
| dog | 8 |
| diff | 4 |

| animal | age |
| --- | --- |
| cat | 10 |
| dog | 13 |
| diff | -3 |

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!
Also to not, I'd like to not save the object. In other words, any way to do this through `tidyverse` would be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, how about:

```
bind_rows(df, df %>% summarize(animal = "diff", age = first(age) - last(age)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `add_row` function from `tibble`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
animal  age
cat 10
dog 13")         

df %>% add_row(animal = "diff", age = diff(rev(df$age)))

  animal age
1    cat  10
2    dog  13
3   diff  -3
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm trying to do rev(age) without df$age as I'm making a straight call from another data frame, but it's saying age not found. Any way to do that?

Comment: @J_sdata `rev(age)` is reversing the order of a vector named `age`. If you are referencing from a dataframe, you'll need the `dataframe$column` syntax. In short, replace `df` with your real dataframe name

Comment: You could use `.` instead of `df`, like `df %>% add_row(animal = "diff", age = diff(rev(.[["age"]])))`